# How do I remove an .append() then add an .append()

Tags: javascript, swfobject

This is to show a check for a diagnostic page. I have an .append(not_ok) but when the swf file is 100% loaded I want to remove the not_ok append then add an .append(ok).

```
function callbackfunk(e){
  $(".FlashNotLoaded").css("color", "red").append(not_ok);
  var timer = setInterval(function(){
    if(e.ref.PercentLoaded() === 100){
        $(".FlashLoaded").remove();
        $(".FlashLoaded").css("color", "green").append(ok);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

swfobject.embedSWF("/static/diag/countdown.swf", "flashDiv", "550", "400", "8.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes, callbackfunk);
```

The .append(not_ok) will be removed but the .append(ok) will not replace it. I've tried
.replaceWith(ok) but that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 2):

Generally with jQuery, you do that by leaving both on the page in the same spot. `jQuery(notOkSelector).hide();` and `jQuery(okSelecter).show();`.

Hide makes the object `display:none`, and show reverses this.

**EDIT**: As long as the objects are already in the DOM (by default with `display:none;`)...

To show `notLoaded`:

```
$(".FlashLoaded").hide(); // it doesn't hurt to hide an already hidden object.
var notLoaded = $(".FlashNotLoaded");
notLoaded.css( 'color', 'red' );
notLoaded.show();
```

To hide `notLoaded` and show `ok`:

```
$(".FlashNotLoaded").hide();
var flashLoaded = $(".FlashLoaded");
flashLoaded.show();
flashLoaded.css( 'color', 'green' );
```

**EDIT including your above code:** Your coude may look like the following...

```
function callbackfunk(e){
  $(".FlashLoaded").hide();
  $(".FlashNotLoaded").css("color", "red").show();
  var timer = setInterval(function(){
    if(e.ref.PercentLoaded() === 100){
        $(".FlashNotLoaded").hide();
        $(".FlashLoaded").css("color", "green").show();
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: +1 because this is, in fact, a better practice to hide and show than to remove and append.

Comment: Making modifications to the DOM tree structure is an  **expensive** action. I agree that `.show()`/`.hide()` is the correct approach to accomplish the desired behaviour.

Comment: I Tried this: $(".FlashNotLoaded").css("color", "red").append(not_ok); $(".FlashLoaded").css("color", "green").append(ok).hide();  and then in the if(percentloaded()){ $(".FlashNotOk").hide(); $(".FlashOk").show();} but I lose both of them at this point. Im not sure the correct syntax for this.

Comment: @user1985037 See the above edit. And granted, you could chain them rather than storing them into variables...

Answer (score 0):

this line

```
$(".FlashLoaded").remove();
```

removes the element(s) from the DOM, so the following line can't append anything to the DOM

```
$(".FlashLoaded").css("color", "green").append(ok);
```

I suppose you wanted to remove `ok` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Are you appending new HTML tags? If so you can use jQuery `replaceWiht()` , it replace an existing element with a new element.